# externalinterface.call won't call the JavaScript function - Firefox 3.6

Tags: flash, function, flash-cs5, externalinterface, firefox3.6

I have a function defined in JavaScript like so:

```
function fadeBack() {
    alert("fadeBack called");
};
```

I call that function from my Flash file like so:

```
import flash.external.*;
flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("fadeBack");
```

This works in both Safari and Chrome, but for some reason Firefox won't ever call the function. Still, I can't figure this out. How can I fix it?

Comment: Got this very same problem. Trying to load a file from other domain and interact with Javascript. Any luck so far?

Comment: none so far.  firefox just won't register the function call.  still haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Same. Firefox 10.0.2 here and the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following parameter set in your HTML or JS embed:

```
allowScriptAccess="always"
```

Comment: that didn't do it.  any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using object/embed tags, and/or JavaScript?
If you use the standard Adobe activeContent embed, you'll need to add the allowScriptAccess tag in 3 places (within the object, embed, and script tags).

Comment: Are you testing locally or on a server?

Answer (score 0):

I had the identical problem in Firefox. After I updated to FireFox 6.02, the problem went away - your code should work fine in version 6.02. I cannot confirm in which version of Firefox this issue was resolved.

Comment: Firefox 10.0.2 here and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the lack of an <embed> tag. If you are using SWFObject 2, it no longer adds the <embed> tag inside the <object> tag. I believe that using ExternalInterface in Firefox requires the <embed>.